# Restart C# application without actually closing and re-opening?

Tags: c#, restart

How can i get all of my internal code to work as if I used Application.Restart(), but without actually having the program have to close and reopen?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  Reset a bunch of application state?  Run a specific form?  Why can't you use `Application.Restart()`?

Comment: That depends on the design of your internal code.

Comment: Is it because you are losing the debugging state while running it from VS? If so you can have the application being run in a while loop, and you can set a condition yourself to check whether while condition is met. I have successfully used it in production code.

Comment: @DStanley, i don't want the user to see the application close and reopen when they click cancel. I just want all the internal code to work as if they had used Application.Restart()

Comment: If you restart.you application, then the user **should definitively** see it. And instead of trying to hide problems, you should definitively fix them. And if required, hire more competent developers or rewrite the application if it was poorly writen.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the design of your application it could be as simple as starting a new instance of your main form and closing any existing form instances.  Any application state outside of form variables would need to be reset as well.  There's not a magic "reset" button for applications like it sounds like you're searching for.

One way would be to add a loop to `Program.cs` to keep the app running if the form closes after a "reset":

```
static class Program
{
    public static bool KeepRunning { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        KeepRunning = true;
        while(KeepRunning)
        {
            KeepRunning = false;
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

and in your form (or toolbar, etc.) set the `KeepRunning` variable to `true`:

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // close the form and let the app die
    this.Close();
}

private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // close the form but keep the app running
    Program.KeepRunning = true;
    this.Close();
}
```