# how to reset all variables to the initial state?

Tags: c#, winforms, reset

I need a reset button in my application. How can I reset application and all variables to the initial state? I have something like this

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtNajmensia.Text = ""; //textbox
    txtNajvacsia.Text = ""; //textbox
    txtVacsia.Text = ""; //textbox
    txtVolumeBigest.Text = ""; //textbox
    txtVolumeBigger.Text = ""; //textbox
    txtVolumeSmall.Text = ""; //textbox
    fronta.RemoveRange(0, fronta.Count); //List
    potomci.RemoveRange(0, potomci.Count); //List
    visited.RemoveRange(0, visited.Count); //List
    lblResult.Text = ""; //label
    txtFinalA.Text = ""; //textbox
    txtFinalB.Text = ""; //textbox
    txtFinalC.Text = ""; //textbox
    lblNotFound.Visible = false; //label
    lblFound.Visible = false; //label
    richTextBox1.Text = ""; 
}
```

But when I want to calculate second time with new values I have error that List visited contains no elements.

Comment: You are removing all elements from visited so what do you think would happen?

Comment: Instead of `.RemoveRange()` you can probably just use `.Clear()` or even just instantiate it as a new list.  As for the error, where does that happen?  If you're trying to do something with the list after removing all of the elements then of course it won't have any elements in it...

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @N4TKD When I run the application the first time the list visited is empty. During calculation is filled with values​​. So the question is why it does not work the second time with another values.

Comment: @GrantWinney I have a class State. List<State> visited

Comment: Step through with the debugger and make sure that the values in these variables are what you expect them to be the second time around. It's possible that they are being cleared but not assigned the new values.

Comment: @Andre then I would say after you clear the list you are hitting it again before you add anything back, debug find where and check its element count before you hit it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170827/restart-c-sharp-application-without-actually-closing-and-re-opening
I found this and it helped me

Answer (score 1):

You've indicated that these are lists of states. It seems pointless to clear them out and then populate them again, so remove these lines from your code:

```
fronta.RemoveRange(0, fronta.Count); //List
potomci.RemoveRange(0, potomci.Count); //List
visited.RemoveRange(0, visited.Count); //List
```

I assume you just want to clear the selected values, so try this instead:

```
fronta.SelectedIndex = -1;
potomci.SelectedIndex = -1;
visited.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lists should be

```
_fronta.Clear();
```

and i personally would use string.empty instead of "";

```
txtNajmensia.Text = string.Empty;
```

but as the comment below says this doesnt answer your question. the problem you have is that you are trying to use the list `visited` after you have cleared it. so you can either not clear that list or check that it has a value where you are using it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: +1 for adding an explanation, all the other answers here simply tell OP that his code is ugly with no explanation about the actual error he is getting.

Comment: to be fair his initial question is how to reset values which is what all of the responses are giving.

Comment: I think it's just a poorly named question. He's already resetting the values in the code, then getting an error because the values are empty. :)